# Push Notification working well in ios 8 but not in ios 7

Tags: ios

I am trying to implement push notification in app.

I have done that for ios 8. on iPad OS is ios8. I got push notification on iPad.

on iPhone OS is iOS7. whenever I compile app on iPhone I got error

/* Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x16d246c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}*/

My app delegate methods are

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}

return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
  {
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}

 - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
  {
     NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
 }
```

Appreciate for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message indicates you are using a different signing certificate for iPad/iOS 7 than for iPhone/iOS 8, one without the permission for push notifications set. It has nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your app is picking up the wrong provisioning profile for whatever reason. Does it start working if you explicitly specify the provisioning profile?